# Assigning $i to the other variable in PHP

Tags: php

Hello guys i have seen a code which is really confusing for me ...THe code is .

```
function mysql_fetch_array_nullsafe($result) {
    $ret=array();

    $num = mysql_num_fields($result);
    if ($num==0) return $ret;

    $fval = mysql_fetch_row ($result);
     if ($fval === false) return false;

    $i=0;
     while($i<$num)
        {
            $fname[$i] = mysql_field_name($result,$i);           
            $ret[$i] = $fval[$i];            // enum
            $ret[''.$fname[$i].''] = $fval[$i];    // assoc
            $i++;
        }

    return $ret;
}
```

here `$ret[$i] = $fval[$i];` is assigned ..My question is that i just want to know why we are assigning $i to the variblar $ret..How it works ?..Is the value of $i stored to $ret or $i act as an index of $ret ..

Please help me to understand this ..Thanks in advance ..:)

Comment: `$ret` is an array and `$i` specifies the index of the array

Comment: this is rather bad code

Answer (score 0):

I think variable $i is for the keys of array variable $ret.

Comment: so you saying $i as a key ?..then what would be the corresponding value of the key $i ?

Answer (score 0):

'An array in PHP is actually an ordered map.'

So there's no numeric index in php array, unlike other language. $i is just a hashmap key that turns out to be an integer.

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @william Say when we fetch a row, there're two ways to access each column: by column index and by column name. The 'mysql_fetch_array_nullsafe' provides both of them. So say your sql is 'select id, name from xxx', and you can fetch the name by both $ret[1] and $ret['name'].

Answer (score 0):

$i is just a counter, so you might end up with arrays similar to those:

```
// $fname[$i] = mysql_field_name($result,$i);
$fname[1] => 'field 1';
$fname[2] => 'field 2';
$fname[3] => 'field 3';
//  $ret[$i] = $fval[$i]; 
$ret[1] => 'value1';
$ret[2] => 'value2';
$ret[3] => 'value3';
// $ret[''.$fname[$i].''] = $fval[$i];    // assoc
$ret['field 1'] => 'value1';
$ret['field 2'] => 'value2';
$ret['field 3'] => 'value3';
```

Who ever thought up those lines of code wanted to be able to look up values using both index and field name:

```
$data = $ret[1];
$data = $ret['field 1'];   //Those would both give the same result ('value1').
```

Answer (score 0):

$i acts as the column number from mysql, see illustration below.

|id | name | lastname | address |

| 1 | john | doe      | USA     |

the id will be 0,name will be 1,lastname will be 2, and address will be 3

$ret array used to store the whole sql row from the mysql database.

where are assigning $i to $ret to retrieve the  data from mysql row.

Comment: so suppose $i is assigned to 1 ..and when we call $ret[$i] will it output john ?